# Discord.py Anti-spam ignore channel command broken

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

Hello I am trying to make an ANTI SPAM bot to work on catching spammers and kicking the from the server. My problem though with the code is that it ignores all channels in the guild and not the channels in the json file.
Here is my code can you please take a look and update me on what I did wrong. Thanks

```
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    counter = 0
    with open("spam-bank.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.author.id):
                counter += 1
        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        try:
          with open("channels.json", "r") as r:
            j = json.load(r)
            all_channels = j["channels"]
            return all_channels
          if counter > 3:
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author} has been kicked for spamming')
            await message.guild.kick(message.author,reason="Caught by Anti-Spam for Spamming")
            print(f'{message.author} was kicked')
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        except:
            return

@client.command()
async def ignore(ctx, channel_):
    def add_channel(channel, file="channels.json"):
        with open(file, "r+") as fw:
            j = json.load(fw)
            j["channels"].append(channel)
            with open(file, "w+") as wp:
                wp.write(json.dumps(j))

    try:
        with open("channels.json", "r"):
            pass
    except:
        with open("channels.json", "w+") as wp:
            wp.write('{"channels" : []}')
    finally:
        add_channel(channel_)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
with open("channels.json", "r") as r:
    j = json.load(r)
    all_channels = j["channels"]
    return all_channels
```

When execution hits `return all_channels`, the function ends, and `all_channels` is returned. No code after that will be reached.

Instead, you need to write code to check if the channel the message was sent in is contained in `all_channels` and return/skip only in that case.

One simple way to figure this out in the future is to add lots of temporary print statements, and trace through the function by following the print statements.

```
with open("channels.json", "r") as r:
    j = json.load(r)
    print("loaded json from file")
    all_channels = j["channels"]
    print(f"extracted channels from json: {all_channels}")
    return all_channels
print(f"checking counter: {counter}")
if counter > 3:
   print("user has sent more than 3 messages. Kicking..")
   await message.channel.send(f'{message.author} has been kicked for spamming')
   await message.guild.kick(message.author,reason="Caught by Anti-Spam for Spamming")
   print(f'{message.author} was kicked')
   await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

You'll get an output like

```
loaded json from file
extracted channels from json: [list]
```

And from that, you can easily tell that something's going wrong between that print statement and the next one, because `checking counter: [number]` isn't getting printed.